# Angular-material: md-select moves container element

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bgo6z1nm/) is the jsfiddle

It seems like the `md-options` are colliding with the body margin when the layout-margin directive is applied.

The HTML:

```
<body style="background-color: orange;" layout="row" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="StarterApp" layout-margin layout-fill>
  <div flex="35" class="md-whiteframe-z1 white">
    <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
      <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
      <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can i avoid this annoying collision? The margin is a must have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need, is a `md-content` container.

The documentation on `md-content` is rather limited: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.content/directive/mdContent

It creates a scrollable container. In general, you should at least surround your application/webpage with this container, since it creates the "correct" conditions for other md containers and directives.

Here you go:

```
<md-content>
  <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
    <md-option value="1">One</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">Two</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-content>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bgo6z1nm/1/

UPDATE:
To clarify, you don't NEED the `md-content` container. If you nest these, you will have multiple elements with scrollers. If you don't want to use these, you will have to create margins, padding and other CSS on your own.